# How to read in a value into an array using Scanner

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I don't have any code to show what I am trying to do, because I honestly have *no idea* how to approach this.

What I am trying to do is have the user input how many numbers will be into an array. So basically, this is what I would like to be the output:

> How many students in the class? 3
>
> Enter the marks:
>      76
>      68
>      83
>
> The class average is 75.67 %

I can program everything else, except for the first line. I have no idea how to read in a number into an array, so that the array will be as big as that number.

Thank you.

Comment: Your questions shows no effort from your part ! but you can use ArrayList for that, that way you won't need to input the number of array elements before, you can dynamically add as much element you want

Comment: Read command line programming in java. In main method, you can pass this values `args[]` parameter. for how many student in the class?=arg[0], same way use arg[1],arg[2] like wise for other input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start you will need to set up your scanner to read console input:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You can then use function such as `scanner.next()` or `scanner.nextInt()` to get the input from the console.  Hopefully this gives you some idea of where to start.  If you need to look up more Scanner functions check the [Scanner Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

As far as arrays go you simply need to save the first int input to the console and use this for size:

```
int size = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
int[] array = new int[size];
```

Then you should be able to use a loop to save each individual score.

Comment: I know how to use a scanner. My problem is getting the size of the array to be input by the user of the program.

Comment: have you seen the comment from @Subham Tripathi?

Comment: Sorry I added a line regarding sizing the array

Comment: Yes, I've seen his comment, but I must admit I was a little confused as to what he meant.

Comment: @JamesC.TaylorIV there is no need to parse cuz scanner has nextInt() as well. and there is no need to use array cuz there is arraylist class in Java.

Comment: @deSynthesize what you are trying to do does not make sense at all in a real world. Try to read about arraylist in Java.

Comment: @KickButtowski Either works, I have had issues in the past with Scanner.nextInt().

Comment: @JamesC.TaylorIV what was it?

Comment: @KickButtowski there was an issue where Scanner.nextInt() would skip ints in the input.  Granted this was in Java 4?  It's been a long time honestly.

Comment: @deSynthesize glad to hear it!

Comment: @deSynthesize it seems to work perfectly is not a good reason at all. just plz know that

Answer (score 1):

```java
 import java.util.Scanner; 

 public class TestArrayInputViaConsole {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     double sum = 0;
     double avg = 0;
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter how many students are in the class? ");
     int ArraySize = sc.nextInt();
     int[] marks = new int[ArraySize];
     System.out.println("Enter the marks:");

     for(int i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++) {
       marks[i] = sc.nextInt();
       sum = sum + marks[i]; 
     }

     avg = (sum / ArraySize);
     System.out.println("Average of the class : " + avg);    
   } 
 }
```